# Dynamically load a class from a dex file in Android APIs below 14?

Tags: android, dex

Is there any way to dynamically load a class from a dex file inside a jar in Android APIs below 14?

Comment: DexClassLoader has been added in API level 3

Comment: around the web I have found a lot of examples, but they all in some point use this sintaxis : " DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                         optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                         null,
                                         getClassLoader());
  Class libProviderClazz = null;
  try {
      // Load the library.
      libProviderClazz =
          cl.loadClass("com.example.dex.lib.LibraryProvider"); " .... here, this last call to method "loadClass" requires api 14.

Comment: "loadClass" requires api 14??? Any links to docs?

Comment: eclipse marks this line as error, with this message "Call requires API level 14 (current min is 8): dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader#loadClass". I was searching about BaseDexClassLoader and, in fact, it was added in API 14. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, please advice.

Comment: Hi pskink, thanks for the time spent, the problem was mine, I was using android 4.3 library to make a project for 2.2...duh!? ajaja, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

maybe Lint in android IDE has error. I got same issue. I fixed it by add:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

to my method.
Actually: this method can run in android API 8